# mongodb cannot start with mongo.conf

Tags: linux, mongodb

os is deepin,i can use

> /home/soft/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath=/home/soft/mongodb/data/db --logpath=/home/soft/mongodb/log/mongodb.log --logappend --port 27017 --fork

will normal start mongodb,but when i use the

> mongod --config /usr/local/mongodb/mongodb.conf
>   will cause some problems like this picture
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXMmZ.png)
>   if the picture not display,error code :

```
root@deepin:/# mongod -config /home/soft/mongodb/mongodb.conf 
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 3196
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

after run,the log file picture like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAUNR.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try posting the logs if created any.
2. Check the permissions for folders created, i.e make sure the folders are created as `sudo` [install-mongodb-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963147/install-mongodb-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100)
3. Also try this out [mongodb-wont-start-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100](https://www.crybit.com/mongodb-wont-start-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100/)

Comment: oh,still this situation,the latest edit have log picture

Comment: thanks,i have solve it,the latest abnormal exit cause the problem,and i remove the data directory, recreate data/db,start mongod in normal.