# Not able to send logs to /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log file and not able to mongod is forked and run as a daemon and i coudnt add user

Tags: mongodb

[Error when doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9tEg.png)I am taking course in MongoDB university, They're having a lab section that we need to solve. I am stuck with Chapter 1: The Mongod Lab: Logging to a Different Facility.

I tried using these commands "mongod --logpath /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log" and "mongod --config mongod.conf" after running these couldnt add the user to validate the question

Can anyone help me detail procedure of the question?

1. mongod sends logs to /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log
2. mongod is forked and run as a daemon (this will not work without specifying logpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may use only the configuration file to achieve whatever you need, you can configure a mongo instance to use a certain log file and to fork properly mongodb. As you can see in this [mongodb documentation section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options). You can edit your configuration file like this:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log "
   logAppend: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
```

And then execute mongodb using this command: `mongod --config mongod.conf`

Comment: After exceuting the command `mongod --config mongod.conf` I am getting this error
**about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections
.
forked process: 347
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option**
When i use this command i got same error as above `mongod --fork --logpath /var/mongodb/logs/mongod.log`. if i use without fork i got log file exists.

Comment: you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963147/install-mongodb-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100). I am sure that will solves your problems.