# How can I create a Dockerfile that runs both my nodeJS server and also launches mongodb? All in the same container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I need to be able to run within the same container both: my nodejs server.js and mongodb.

I know it is possible to achieve this with docker-compose or with two separate containers but that is not an option here. I need both services running on the same container.

My Dockerfile is something like this:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY server.js public/ ./
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 27017
CMD service mongodb start && node server.js
```

Then at some point my server.js needs to call the mongodb like this:

```
const uri = 'mongodb://172.0.0.1:27017';
```

However when I try to build my container I get:

```
E: Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Your URI is wrong. It should be 127, not 172.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you want to do this, you can create two different Dockerfiles as well, but anyway.

```
FROM node:16

# Install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget gnupg && \
    wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb-org

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY server.js public/ ./

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 27017

CMD service mongod start && node server.js
```

```
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
```

Comment: I had to change the end to CMD ["mongod"]
CMD ["node", "server.js"]  bc i was getting mongod: unrecognized service but now with that change it seems to work. Yet my nodeJs is unable to interact with the mongodb using 127.0.0.1 or localhost, what should i use?

Comment: Not so familiar with mongo, but I guess you need to add the schema name... `const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name';
`

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the dockerfile only admits one CMD, so I could not really get i t to work. With the original answer I get mongod: unrecognized service

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to run both MongoDB and Application in same container, Anyway you can do it like this;

```
FROM node:14

# Install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y mongodb 

# Create a directory to hold the application code inside the image
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the application code into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY . .

# Install npm packages
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

# Run mongod to start MongoDB and server.js with Node.js in the background
CMD mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log && node server.js
```

I've used mongoose NPM Package to connect to MongoDB,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoDBUri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase';

mongoose.connect(mongoDBUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected successfully to MongoDB');
});
```

Comment: WIth the fork I get an Error: child process failed, exited with 100

Comment: Can you check this URL please there are some insights about how to fix this issue,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963147/install-mongodb-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100